# get contacts those are not related to any group

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts, contactscontract

I am working on the displaying the contacts group wise in android application. So I got all the group contacts from the particular group but now I want to get the contacts those are not in any of the group (NOT ASSIGNED).

So what can be the value of GROUP_ROW_ID in the contacts's in case of no group **ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID** ?

If there any solution you know please let me know.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: We want contacts display in listview..

Comment: yes but only those contacts those are not related to any of the group means NOT ASSIGNED.

Comment: not much idea of you query but just know all contacts display in listview.

Comment: see I want to know the query to get contacts that are not related to any of the group.

Answer (score 1):

Please use,

```
 ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID = null;
```

This will get non-group contacts.

Comment: Has someone tested this?
Do RawContacts without a group have a data row with Mimetype ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE? When this work it must be `[...] ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID + " IS NULL";`

Answer (score -1):

you can retrieve all contacts as a cursor.

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(   ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null,null, null);
```

now we have cusror with contacts and get diffrent value from cusror.

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
String name =cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));

String phoneNumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
 }
```

see this one http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-read-contact-and-display-in.html

Comment: But i want only contacts which are not any group. This will give you all the contacts and numbers.